# PHP Composer does not clone symfony/assetic-bundle properly

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, assetic

I am trying to install Symfony on CentOS Linux wih PHP 5.6 and cPanel installed.

When I run `composer require symfony/assetic-bundle` , once adding bundle to the AppKernelphp, symfony (app/console too) stops working and keeps logging this error:

`[10-Jun-2016 22:00:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle' not found in /home/avid24/public_html/app/AppKernel.php on line 19`

After checking the vendor directory, turns out that composer has downloaded a single compressed file with a random name, I could extract it with unzip. but problem still exists!

This environment works properly on windows and I could easily update symfony and its components using composer.

Any help? Anyone with the same experience ?

Comment: Try deleting your vendor directory, running `composer install` then `composer update symfony/assetic-bundle`. `composer install` will just install everything that is in your `composer.lock` file (so everything that Composer has actually installed and locked at the specific version). `composer update ..` will attempt to just update the AsseticBundle to the latest version available that fits the specifications in your `composer.json` (the your `composer require..` would have added to... I think). Hopefully, that will just pull the actual directory rather than compressed package.

Comment: Turns out the composer is faulty! to some point composer worked but now it's not functioning !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I eventually figured out the problem!

I enabled suhosin extension which prevents the composer and other similar command prompt php scripts from a proper execution.

As a temporary solution I copied php.ini and disabled unnecessary extensions and put it next to my project and call composer this way

```
$php -c ../composer-php.ini ~/composer  ......
```

I'll create a script to make the life easier

I didn't find any resource which describes coexistence of composer and suhosin extension, so I'm not sure if this is the ultimate solution but the root cause is identified.

If anybody makes workaround this subject I'd be more than happy to know about it.